# How to export a csv file based on a SQL query programatically

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv

I am not a SQL expert, so this may be a really obvious thing to those of you who are experts.  Anyway, I have created an application that has to generate a csv file based on a SQL Query.  In reading the internet tips on how to export a CSV file from SQL they all refer you to using Management Studio, right-click on the query results and use the Save-AS technique.  That will not practical for my purposes as the CSV file has to generated at the push of a button within my application.  I was hoping (and expected) to be able to do it with a pass through query or stored procedure, but I'm not seeing that SQL 2008 supports this.  Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What language is your application written in?

Answer (score 0):

The answer will vary depending on the language that your application is written in but to use C# as an example.  A common way is to populate a dataset from the sql query and then burn through the dataset using loops to generate the csv.

Here is an example of that approach from the interweb.

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2009/12/16/c-convert-dataset-to-csv

Here is another example using VB

http://www.vbnettutorial.net/?Id=119&Desc=Export-CSV-from-Dataset

The complexity of the data may require that you get fancy... (for example does your data have double quotes, coma's, binary data???