# Save CSV with UTF-8 encoding on export using SQL Server Management Studio 2005

Tags: sql-server, csv, utf-8, ucs2

I am trying to export a CSV file using SQL Server Management Studio 2005 and I have tried clicking on the drop down button next to Save and selecting encoding UTF, but it still saves as UCS-2 little endian encoding.

Is it possible to have it in UTF-8 encoding without having to open with Notepad++ and save as UTF-8?  Extra step and all.

Answer (score 1):

since I needed an app to do this for me I used vb to do it using the following links help
http://www.vbnettutorial.net/?Id=119&Desc=Export-CSV-from-Dataset
[How to export a csv file based on a SQL query programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133705/how-to-export-a-csv-file-based-on-a-sql-query-programatically)

Answer (score 1):

Since MS SQL Server only output as UCS-2 Little Endian or ASII encoding, you may use bcp to call a little C# program to convert it in to UTF-8

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UCS2toUTF8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("exampe: UCS2toUTF8 [filepath]");
                return;
            }

            var filename = args[0];

            var filestream = File.OpenRead(filename);

            var BOM = new byte[3];

            filestream.Read(BOM, 0, BOM.Length);

            if (BOM[0] != (byte)255 && BOM[1] != (byte)254 ) //0xff 0xfe 0x48
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This isn't UCS-2LE");
                return;
            }else if (BOM[0] == 0xEF && BOM[1] == 0xBB && BOM[2] == 0xBF)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is UTF-8");
                return;
            }

            filestream.Close();

            byte[] content = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

            byte[] utf8Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Convert(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, content);

            byte[] newArray = new byte[utf8Bytes.Length - 3];

            Array.Copy(utf8Bytes, 3, newArray, 0, newArray.Length);

            File.WriteAllBytes(filename, newArray);
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that if you want UTF-8 with BOM, you need to do some modification.